# Compute MLE and MSE

Tags: statistics

$X_1,\ldots , X_n$ i.i.d. and $f_{\theta}(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}x^{\frac{1}{\theta}-1}\hbox{I}_{(0,\infty)}(x)$

Compute $MLE\theta$ and $MSE(\hat \theta)$

I had no problem with computing $MLE\theta$ which is $\hat\theta=-\ln((x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}) $, but i have a problem now with computing $MSE(\hat\theta)$.

I started with:

$MSE(\hat\theta)=Var(\hat\theta)+(b(\hat\theta))^2$ where $b$ is bias.

But I have a problem even computing a bias.

To be exact, my biggest problem is to compute $\mathbb{E}[\hat\theta]$. I competly don't know what to do, since there is a logarithm in there. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: In order to provide a bit of assistance, remember that $E[\hat{\theta}]=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\hat{\theta}f(x)dx$. (Replace the integral with a summation in the discrete case.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspecting that you made some mistakes.

1) Probably the support of the original r.v is $[0,1]$ and not $(0,\infty)$, otherwise it is not a valid density function.

2) You should check your calculations, the MLE should be $$
\hat{\theta}_n = -\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x_i)}{n}.$$

3) Lets start with the expected value, 
$$
\mathbb{E}\theta_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum\mathbb{E}(-\ln X_i)
$$

so, denote $Y=-\ln X$, hence

$$
F_Y(y) = P(-\ln X \le Y) = 1-F_X(e^{-y}),
$$
thus, 
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-y/\theta}, \quad y \ge 0.
$$
That is an exponential r.v, therefore, $\mathbb{E}\theta_n = \theta$. Can you proceed to the MSE?